# Understanding Importance Sampling Convergence

Tags: probability-theory

I'm reading Radford M. Neal's paper *Annealed Importance Sampling*, where in section
$1$ page $2$ he discusses importance sampling. He writes [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/9803008.pdf) :

> Suppose that we are interested in a distribution for some quantity, $x$,
> with probabilities or probability densities that are proportional to
> the function $f(x)$. Suppose also that computing $f(x)$ for any $x$ is
> feasible, but that we are not able to directly sample from the
> distribution it defines. However, we are able to sample from some
> other distribution that approximates the one defined by $f(x)$, whose
> probabilities or probability densities are proportional to the
> function $g(x)$, which we are also able to evaluate. We base our
> estimates on a sample of $N$ independent points, $x_1 \ldots, x_N$,
> generated from the distribution defined by $g(x)$. For each $x_i$, we
> compute an importance weight as follows: $w_i = f(x_i) / g(x_i)$

> We can then estimate the expectation of $a(x)$ with respect to the
> distribution defined by $f(x)$ by $\bar{a} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N} w_i a(x_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} w_i}$.
> Provided $g(x) \neq 0$ whenever $f(x) = 0$, it is easy to see that $N^{−1} \sum_{i} w_i$ will converge as $N \rightarrow \infty$ to $Z_f / Z_g$, where $Z_f = \int f(x) dx$ and $Z_g =  \int g(x) dx$ are the normalizing constants for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. One can also
> see that $\bar{a}$ will converge to the expectation of $a(x)$ with respect to
> the distribution defined by $f(x)$.

I'm having difficulty understand these last two statements.
Firstly, looking at

$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} N^{-1} \sum_{i} \frac{f(x_i)}{g(x_i)} = \frac{\int f(x)dx}{\int g(x)dx}$$

From what I understand, $f(x)/g(x)$ is a random variable with an associated density $u(x)$, and by the law of large numbers I would think that  $$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} N^{-1} \sum_{i} \frac{f(x_i)}{g(x_i)} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} u(x)$$ but I'm not sure how to relate this to  $Z_f / Z_g$.

Secondly, on the convergence of $\bar{a}$, what I'm imagining the author means is that:

$$\mathbb{E}_{x \sim \bar{g}(x)}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N} w_i a(x_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} w_i} = \mathbb{E}_{x \sim \bar{f}(x)}[a(x)]$$

where $\bar{f}(x) = f(x)/Z_f$ but I'm not sure how to see this. Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since our random sample $x_1,\dots, x_N$ comes from a distribution, that is proportional to $g$, we must have that the density is
$\frac{1}{\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) dx}g(x)$. This implies, due to the law of large numbers, that
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} N^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}z(x_i) = \frac{1}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)\:dx} \int_{\mathbb{R}}z(x)g(x) \: dx$$
for all measurable function $z$, such that $x\mapsto z(x)g(x)$ is integrable. In particular if we choose $z = \frac{f}{g}$ we get that
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} N^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{f(x_i)}{g(x_i)} = \frac{1}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)\:dx} \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}g(x) \: dx = \frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\:dx}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)\:dx}.$$
Also if we instead choose $z= a \cdot \frac{f}{g}$ we get
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} N^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}a(x_i)\frac{f(x_i)}{g(x_i)} = \frac{1}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)\:dx} \int_{\mathbb{R}}a(x)\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}g(x) \: dx = \frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}}a(x)f(x)\:dx}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)\:dx}.$$
Now if we consider the quotient of the two limits above we get
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \frac{N^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^N a(x_i)w_i}{N^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^N w_i  } = \Big(\frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\:dx}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)\:dx}  \Big)^{-1}\frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}}a(x)f(x)\:dx}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)\:dx} =
\frac{\int_\mathbb{R} a(x) f(x)\: dx}{\int_\mathbb{R}  f(x)\: dx},
$$
which is the expectation of $a(x)$, when $x \sim \frac{f(x)}{Z_f}$.